# ayuda en una list comprehension python con doble for

Tags: python, lista

tengo estos diccionarios definidos

```
SustantivoMS = {#diccionario sustantivo masculino singular
    'perro':'PERRO',
    'gato':'GATO',
    'arbol':'ARBOL'   
}
ArticuloMS = {#diccionario para articulos masculinos singular
    'el':'EL',
    'un':'UN'
}
```

y este modo de virificar las combinaciones de sustantivo y articulo

```
cont = 0
for articuloms in ArticuloMS:
    for sustms in SustantivoMS:
        if (ArticuloMS[articuloms] == oracion[0] and SustantivoMS[sustms] == oracion[1]):
            cont = 1
            break
```

Quisiera saber si este modo se puede simplificar en una list comprehension,no las manipulo muy bien

la oración es una lista bien puede ser

```
oracion=['EL','PERRO'] como ejemplo, pero claro son palabras del diccionario
```

Comment: Por favor explica cuál es el resultado final que buscas. Esto es un [mcve] para que podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Efrainrodc, mejor que lo intentes, y si tienes un problema, lo muestres por medio de un __[mcve]__. Debes tener en cuenta que _si tu ejemplo funciona_, __no hay ningún problema que resolver__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien dices usando "comprensión de listas" obtienes un código más compacto y en algunos casos más legible. Para tu ejemplo, la lista de combinaciones se puede generar así:

```
[(a,s) for a in ArticuloMS for s in sustantivoMS]
```

si luego tienes que hacer algo con la misma simplemente

```
for c in [(a,s) for a in ArticuloMS for s in sustantivoMS]:
    pass
```

Y por el mismo precio, la otra forma es usando la rutina de producto cartesiano

```
import itertools
for c in itertools.product(ArticuloMS,sustantivoMS):
    pass
```